# Remove duplication from two compressed files

Tags: bash

I have two compressed files, with values organized in columns.

I need to check the first column in each one, and delete the duplicated values from the first file, and keep it in the second one.

Comment: Can you give sample input files and expected output please?

Comment: Each file contains huge number of data, the first column of each file contains IDs, such as 
55441
55442
55486

Comment: How are they compressed? What algorithm?

Comment: they are .gz files

Comment: @Minix, They are `.CSV` files, Ordinary ASCII files with columns of data separated by delimiter **,** on each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the paths to your files into the script and then run it.

Tested the script with these example files:

`file1.csv`:

```
11,0
12,b
14,z
```

`file2.csv`:

```
12,a
13,b
14,c
```

`out.csv`:

```
11,0
```

`del_dup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE1=./file1.csv
FILE2=./file2.csv
FILE3=./out.csv

IFS=$'\n' 
for line in $( cat $FILE1 ); do
        ID1="$( echo $line | cut -d ',' -f1 )"
        if [ -z "$( cat $FILE2 | grep ^"$ID1" )" ]; then
                echo $line >> $FILE3
        fi
done
```

Comment: Forgot the decompression, but with two files, that can be done manually, I guess.